# Help in solving Number Theory

Tags: number-theory

If n is a positive integer and $(n + 1)(n + 3)$ is odd, then $(n + 2)(n + 4)$ must be a multiple of which one of the following?

$(A)\;3 \quad(B)\; 5 
\quad (C)\; 6 \quad  (D) \;8 \quad(E) \;16$

Answer (score 3):

If $(n+1)(n+3)$ is odd, this means $n+1$ and $n+3$ are both odd and therefore $n=2k$ is even. So:

$$(n+2)(n+4)=(2k+2)(2k+4)=4(k+1)(k+2)$$

The product of two consecutive numbers is even and so $(n+2)(n+4)$ is divisible by $8$